# ISO C String Concatenation unwanted @ character at the very end

Tags: c

This code prints foobar@. Here the @ should not come.I do not know why this is coming.This is ISO C. I hope someone fixed this problem earlier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str1 = (char*)"foo";
    char *str2 = (char*)"bar";

    char ccat[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)];

    strncpy(&ccat[0], str1, strlen(str1));
    strncpy(&ccat[strlen(str1)], str2, strlen(str2));

    puts(str1);
    puts(str2);
    puts(ccat);
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting `"foo"`? That's completely unnecessary and confusing.

Comment: ccat needs +1 for its length for `\0`

Comment: It is not ISO C. It is your bug. Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Learn about [snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) and [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html). Ad your question should have an [MCVE] and that requires to explain what you understood and tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember in a C string you'll need the total length **plus one more byte for the NUL terminator character**. That means you need:

```
char ccat[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1];
```

Since you didn't allocate enough room for the final character you get random garbage there, like `@` or it could be anything. Or nothing.

Secondly you were preventing `strncpy` from applying the complete string, NUL terminator included. That resulted in an incomplete write. Proper termination is necessary, so the quick fix is `strlen(str1)+1`, but you should be describing the *length of the receiving buffer* to prevent overflows, not the length of the thing you're writing.

You'll also either need to add a NUL terminator manually, or change how you add in the strings. This approach might be better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str1 = "foo";
    char *str2 = "bar";

    char ccat[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1];

    // The length limit on the first one is the length of the buffer - 1
    strncpy(ccat, str1, sizeof(ccat)-1);
    // The length limit on the second is that minus the length of what's in there
    strncat(ccat, str2, sizeof(ccat)-strlen(ccat)-1);

    puts(str1);
    puts(str2);
    puts(ccat);

    return 0;
}
```

It's worth noting that your compiler may warn (`-Wall`) about common overflow problems if you mess up, like this example:

```
the value of the size argument in 'strncat' is too large, might lead to a buffer overflow [-Wstrncat-size]
```

Comment: @chux That's a good point, I've added a more complete example.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

    char str1[] = "foo";
    char str2[] = "bar";


    char ccat[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)];

    strncpy(&ccat[0], str1, strlen(str1));
    strncpy(&ccat[strlen(str1)], str2, strlen(str2));
    ccat[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)]='\0';

    puts(str1);
    puts(str2);
    puts(ccat);
    printf("\n%s", ccat);
}
```

Comment: You're just smashing a random bit of memory there in your out-of-bounds write.

Comment: `char ccat[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)];` is too small for the _string_ `"foobar"`.  `ccat[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)]='\0';` is UB (writing outside array).  `puts(ccat);` is UB.  (function expects a pointer to a string.)

Comment: Answers are also expected to have some explanation what the code does and what was changed.